# FullCalendar drag event onto external event list which is positioned over the calendar

Tags: javascript, css, events, fullcalendar, drag

I'm creating a calendar view with an external event list which is positioned over the calendar. To save place it expands when hovering over it ([Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/MrRious/pen/BYxwLK)).

My problem is:
I want to drag an event from the calendar onto the events list and render correctly in front of the events list while dragging but the dragged event of the calendar is always behind the event list.

Setting the following CSS doesn't help. The dragged event stays behind the event list.

```
.fc-draggable {
    z-index: 5 !important;
}
```

Setting the following CSS renders the dragged event over the list, but hovering over the list isn't recognized anymore and it doesn't expand.

```
.fc-view {
    z-index: unset;
}
```

Anyone got an idea how i can fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the whole calendar is always behind the event list. So I don't get what you mean or what you're expecting? Do you want the event list to hide when trying to drag the event onto a day which is hidden by the list? Or something else? Frankly, putting the list over the top of the calendar is a bit bizarre anyway. Are you expecting users to have such limited screen space that a list won't fit by the side or at the top/bottom (bearing in mind that fullCalendar isn't suited to mobile devices anyway)?

Comment: BTW your second bit of code doesn't seem to cause the list not to hover/expand (at least not in Chrome anyway), it seems fine.

Comment: I want to drag an event from the calendar onto the events list. And when you are dragging an event the second solution causes the events list to not hover but render the event in front of the list which i need.

The list needs to be over the calendar.

Comment: "And when you are dragging an event the second solution causes the events list to not hover". No it doesn't. It hovers fine in the latest Chrome, I don't know about other browsers

Comment: I'm also using latest Chrome and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your description of the issue then. Can you make a video of it? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLMxmG has when `.fc-view {
    z-index: unset;
}` included. When I drag an event around it always stays above the event list, and the event list still expands when needed.

Comment: Not at the moment sorry. I describe the procedure:

Comment: however in IE11 it doesn't work the same.

Comment: Drag an event from events list to calender (works fine). Then drag the event back to the events list. Normally the events list should expand when hovering over it now, but in my case with the second solution active, it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think this is related to CSS. It's because fullCalendar thinks you're trying to drag it onto the days of the calendar which happen to be underneath the events list. That's normal and expected behaviour in fullCalendar. It's related to what's defined as the droppable zone, I think. Having two drop zones on top of each other really isn't going to ever work properly.

Comment: Possible... Thank you!

Comment: I think it's almost certainly that. If you move the events list to the side of the calendar it works perfectly.